# How to make certain part of a large static text bold or italic in UITextView in Swift 2

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextview

I just have three months learning experience in Swift, so please forgive my ignorance.

I am doing a Book reading app and populating the chapters using a json file.

The **problem** i am facing is :
1. This chapter contents can have sub headers or quotes in between them which are supposed to be in bold or some in italics. I am not sure how to identify these parts and display them in bold/italics.

I had **two** approaches to this:
1. Use just a UITextView to display chapter contents.  In this case, my json looks like this :

```
  "book": {
    "name": "Fairy Tale,",
    "chapters": [
      {
        "chapterNumber": 1,
        "chapterName": "Tale First",
        "chapterContents": "<\bold>This is a first heading.And it will be bold.Contents come here<\bold>.This will be plain text. Non bold.<\bold>This is a second heading.<\bold> And it will be bold.Contents come here.This will be plain text. Non bold."
      }
    ]
  }
```

Put some string like <\bold> and use it to split it. And then show the strings in bold for heading and non bold for the contents. But this does not look like a solution, and i am not sure, if i can split this up properly and also do this for all the 18 chapters.

2. Using a UITableViewCell and put UITextView within it. And pass an array of chapterContents with its heading and contents. So my json looks like this.

`"book": {
    "name": "Fairy Tales,",
    "chapters": [
      {
        "chapterNumber": 1,
        "chapterName": "Tale First",
        "chapterContents": [
          {
            "contentHeader": "This is a first heading.And it will be bold.",
            "contents": "Contents come here.This will be plain text. Non bold."
          },
          {
            "contentHeader": "This is a second heading.And it will be bold.",
            "contents": "Contents come here.This will be plain text. Non bold."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }`

and then iterate over the chapterContents array, and put each one in one TableViewCell containing a UILabel for showing the contentHeader, and UITextView for showing the contents. But with this, i will have to remove the scroll since i want the chapters to scroll for the entire length of the screen and not limit to the cell height. And am not sure if this is how the book reading app should be done.

These both dont look like feasible solutions.
Could some one please help me to know
1. if there is some other component that supports this kind of display or a different solution that i can implement to figure out the bold and non bold parts.?
2. Or if using the UITextView inside a UITableViewCell is one of the ways of doing it.?

Thanks in advance. I am using Swift 2.

Comment: [NSMutableAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/)

Comment: you can get html via json and parse into uitextview by mutableattribitedString

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   let json : NSString  = <h1>Heading</h1><p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> 
        is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <h1>Heading</h1><p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
        Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. 
        It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>


    let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(
        data: json.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
        options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
        documentAttributes: nil)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        yourTextView.attributedText = attrStr
    })
```

Comment: That part worked. Thanks. But i need to provide different font family, font size for headings and content. I tried with the `<h1 style= font-family: \"Athelas\" font-size: 19.00pt; >Heading</h1>`. Those dont seem to work. Could you please tell me how do i add that?

Comment: This worked. `<h1 style=\"text-align:center; font-size: 23pt; font-family: \'Athelas\'; color: grey; \" >Heading</h1>`. Thanks @Muhammad Noman

Comment: use  this in your project it will save your time all way https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna

Comment: Thanks.. Will look that up.